# jquery php embedding DOM element same problem

Tags: php, jquery

When i embed or use php loops to create multiple div's with some id.
I want each of them to use with jquery. Say anything like simple hide/show interface.

But as the id is the same it wont work. I assign a variable lets say $i to php loop for the reference of uniqueness. I can assign id to a DOM element with like

```
           <div id="element-<php echo $i ?>">Bla Bla </div>
```

Php echoes out here perfectly but how do i use it with jquery something like this:

```
        $("#element"+<?php echo $i ?>).toggle();
```

Here it doesnt works.

How do i do it correctly and where am i going wrong ?

Sorry for bad english.

Thanks

Comment: You're not closing your PHP tag in the javascript section.  Is that what the actual code is like or is this just a transcription error?

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to put them here. But in the actual code they are there. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the proper syntax for a php code is:

```
<?php

//code

?>
```

So here you can clearly see what is the error:

```
<php echo $i ?>
```

It should be:

```
<?php echo $i; ?>
```

**Updated answer:**

```
<?php
 for ($k=0;$k<=100;$k++)
  echo '<div id="element-'.$k.'" onclick="toggleID('.$k.')">Here is the content of div $k</div>';
?>

<script>
 function toggleID(id)
 {
  $("#element"+id).toggle();
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to put them here. But in the actual code they are there. Sorry :)

Comment: Then you must have corrected the code. By the way, i got your question. let me update the answer.

Comment: Ahaha i am sorry. My mom was raging at me to close the system so i hurredky typed it. Btw thanks a lot :) :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<script>
 function togl(id)
 {
  $("#element"+id).toggle();
 }
</script>

<?php
 for ($i=0;$<10;$i++)
  echo '<div id="element-'.$i.'" onclick="toggle('.$i.')">Bla Bla </div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include the dash in the jQuery code and you also don't need to concatenate the strings:

```
$("#element-<?php echo $i; ?>").toggle();
```

PHP is interpreted on the server and JavaScript is interpreted on the client. You should never consider concatenating strings between these environments since they are two different steps in serving your application.

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to put them here. But in the actual code they are there. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didnt' close your php statement:

You're missing the ";?>"

try this:

```
;?>
```

ath the end of your statement

**EDITED:**

plus you're missing the "-" between "element" and "id":

```
Ex. element-1
```

try including the "minus":

$("#element-"+id)

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to put them here. But in the actual code they are there. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code for the javascript should be like this instead of what you posted.

```
$("#element-"+<?php echo $i ?>).toggle();
```

However I wouldn't recommend this approach as it's not very efficiant. It will trigger a lot of jQuery lookups.

You'd be better off giving all the divs in question a class and then using the class to reference them in jQuery.

```
<div class="toggleThis" id="element-<php echo $i ?>">Bla Bla </div>

$(".toggleThis").toggle();
```

Comment: But this will toggle all the divs when someone clicks it. And what i wany i is just that it toggles only the relevant div

Comment: OK, then the ID approach is probably the correct one in this case.  The correction I wrote to your original code should work.  But I don't think the - character is legal for ID, so you might want to replace it with a _ character

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot have the same ID's. But if you just want simple show/hide functionality, you should add a class to your div instead of an ID. So..

```
class="toggableDiv"
```

and then in jQuery

```
$(".toggableDiv").click();
```